# How to solved this React native error "Task :app : checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED"

Tags: react-native

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyIGM.pn)

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 24
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
    classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

How to solve "Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED" this React native error

- [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj6tK.png)
- [Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nFoQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc66Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Install the JDK 11 from oracle https://www.oracle.com/mx/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html

then uninstall your java 8 and change the enviromental variable JAVA_HOME to
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11 (be sure this is the path where your jdk is installed)

I recommend you to change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 at least
(download the api 31 using android studio)

finally restart the computer!